# R - using apply with a custom function with multiple arguments

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

Currently I've been only able to do this with a For-Loop:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(PS_check_no_match)){
  add_error("Warning"
            ,"professional services QA Check"
            ,PS_check_no_match$msg[i]
            ,FALSE)  
}
```

I'm trying to do something like this to replace the for loop.

```
apply(PS_check_no_match$msg
      ,1
       ,add_error("Warning"
                  ,"professional services QA Check"
                  ,PS_check_no_match$msg
                  ,FALSE))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function of the argument you want to loop through:

```
apply(PS_check_no_match$msg
      ,1
      ,function(x) add_error("Warning"
                  ,"professional services QA Check"
                  ,x
                  ,FALSE))
```

Comment: Thank you!  Take to make a slight tweak to avoid the 'dim(X) must have a positive length' error but you got me on the right track.

Comment: It may work to use `sapply()` instead. It would be the same except that you would drop the ",1" argument.